# How to add a list of global components in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new in Nextjs and I want to add a list of components and utilities to all of my pages in Nextjs. How can I make them all available in my components without importing them one by one.

Also some utilities might be needed in `getInitialProps` function in pages like `axios` or in my case `client` of `Apollo`.

I don't expect some one write me a whole config file for `Nextjs.config` just help me to understand the configuration of next deeper.

thanks in  advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to do dynamic import on each page, for each component and utility instead of making components global. By doing so Next.js will create a small chunks or "pages" without any unused components.

If you load components globally, every page would increase in size but actually not use these components or utilities. **It defeats a purpose of code-splitting**.

**It breaks modularity of your code**, because components/pages (modules) will depend on some global utilities implicitly.

If you have too many imports in your component or page, probably, it's a sign to encapsulate that extra functionality by extracting it to it's own component.

Controversially, you could try to add global utilities in [Custom "App"](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

For example, you could pass a React component to all Next.js pages via props of custom `App`.

**_app.js**

```
import Icon from '../components/Icon';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} icon={Icon} />
}
```

As all pages are instancing from the `App`, every page would have this component in the `props`.

**index.js**

```
const Home = props => (
    <div>
        <props.icon><props.icon/>
    </div>
);
```

If you have many components you could group them into list and assign to a single prop, so you can use it like:

**index.js**

```
const Home = props => (
    <div>
        <props.components.icon/>
        <props.components.anotherIcon/>
    </div>
);
```

On a side note, it's suggested to use `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` for pages instead of `getInitialProps` since Next.js 9.3.

Suggested reading:

[Next.js Data fetching (getInitialProps)](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#recommended-use-getstaticprops-or-getserversideprops-instead)

[React.js Code-Splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)

Comment: lets imagine that there is a custom icon component I wrote and I need it to be included in almost every components I create (or in my case the pages) what should I do? 
mostly I was looking for a tweak that add something in webpack so it adds the global components I need in every page. Do you happen to know anything about it?

Comment: @SaeedAmin, I've added an example of how it can be done with the Custom "App".

Comment: thanks for your time. Is it ok with you to reach you by your mail for further questions?